# Modifying whole column Type Code PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have been doing a program to format an xls, opening, modifying and saving it.

It is taking so much time that is showing me a timeout error so I would like to change my functions execute a change of TypeCode on the cells over the whole column and not on every cell.

My current sentence is:

```
$sheet->getStyle($currentICell)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('0000');
```

and that is inside a loop while until the last Row is reached.

I wonder if there is a function to do something like `setFormatCode` over a column and not just the cell.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set a style for every individual cell, that's simply an enormous processing and memory overhead; set style for a range of cells in a single call:

```
$sheet->getStyle('A1:A255')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('0000');
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing closing ' on A1:A255 - also, couldn't just `'A'` also be used for whole column without row numbers needed?

Comment: Column or Row styles aren't supported; only styling for cells and cell ranges; so no, `$sheet->getStyle('A')` or `$sheet->getStyle(1)` will not work (and should thrown an exception)